# Segeo UI Light font not showing Extra light font weight on windows phone device

Tags: fonts, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Segeo UI Light font in my application. I have a textblock with following style applied

```
   <TextBlock x:Uid="NewsTextBlock" Text="News heading" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="ExtraLight" Style="{StaticResource PageHeadingStyle}"/>


 <Style x:Name="PageHeadingStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segeo UI Light"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
</Style>
```

Extra light weight is showing on emulator but not on device need help to make the font extra light.